# CouchDB: Not Serving Futon

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb, apache, couchdb-futon

I've installed CouchDB in Ubuntu 11.10. I have an HTTPD server running (which functions properly) as well as all of the prerequisites for CouchDB.

I've started up CouchDB in the background for a user on the system:

> sudo -i -u bpetruk couchdb -b

And it tells me that it's started, and "it's time to relax". Unfortunately, I can't relax just yet -- because even though the server has loaded, I can't access Futon from the standard http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils location.

Here's some error output from the startup routine. Horrible, I know lol. It seems to have just dumped some JSON to the terminal:

> Apache CouchDB 1.2.0 (LogLevel=info) is starting. [error] [<0.96.0>]
>   {error_report,<0.31.0>,
>                       {<0.96.0>,crash_report,
>                        [[{initial_call,{couch_auth_cache,init,['Argument__1']}},
>                          {pid,<0.96.0>},
>                          {registered_name,[]},
>                          {error_info,
>                           {exit,
>                            {{badmatch,{error,eacces}},
>                             [{couch_auth_cache,ensure_users_db_exists,2},
>                              {couch_auth_cache,open_auth_db,0},
>                              {couch_auth_cache,reinit_cache,1},
>                              {couch_auth_cache,init,1},
>                              {gen_server,init_it,6},
>                              {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]},
>                            [{gen_server,init_it,6},
>                             {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}},
>                          {ancestors,
>                           [couch_secondary_services,couch_server_sup,<0.32.0>]},
>                          {messages,[]},
>                          {links,[<0.94.0>,<0.97.0>]},
>                          {dictionary,[]},
>                          {trap_exit,true},
>                          {status,running},
>                          {heap_size,610},
>                          {stack_size,24},
>                          {reductions,227}],
>                         [{neighbour,
>                           [{pid,<0.97.0>},
>                            {registered_name,[]},
>                            {initial_call,{couch_event_sup,init,['Argument__1']}},
>                            {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}},
>                            {ancestors,
>                             [couch_auth_cache,couch_secondary_services,
>                              couch_server_sup,<0.32.0>]},
>                            {messages,[]},
>                            {links,[<0.96.0>,<0.89.0>]},
>                            {dictionary,[]},
>                            {trap_exit,false},
>                            {status,waiting},
>                            {heap_size,233},
>                            {stack_size,9},
>                            {reductions,32}]}]]}} {"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{bad_return,{{couch_app,start,[normal,["/usr/local/etc/couchdb/default.ini","/usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},{'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,shutdown}},[{couch_server_sup,start_server,1},{application_master,start_it_old,4}]}}}}}},[{couch,start,0},{init,start_it,1},{init,start_em,1}]}}

Equally frustrating is the fact that defining the -s flag on couchdb (which is supposed to print the status of the background process) yields absolutely nothing! So I can't provide information in that regard, either.

Are there any common issues I may be blind to in my first foray into the CouchDB world? I'm really stuck on this one!

Comment: Gah, just file permission issues. I thought I added permissions to all required files, but I apparently missed some. Just chowned the entire CouchDB directory and it fired up perfectly. I'm not too concerned about security on this machine; it's just for testing, anyway.

Comment: If you solved the problem add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by "**{{badmatch,{error,eacces}}**" in the third line of the error output above, CouchDB was running into some file permissions errors, and couldn't properly write to some file. I wasn't able to determine which file was causing this problem, but taking ownership of the entire CouchDB directory solved the problem.